# Is there a way to place a file into AWS S3 using IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, amazon-s3, ironpython, spotfire

I had AWS S3 bucket information like Bucket Name,Access Key,Secret Key and having access to that bucket. Now i am trying to place file using IronPython from spotfire. Please someone help me out with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible way could be the use of the SDK for .NET   https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-net/